# How to set system modified date on file in Mule

Tags: file, mule, file-transfer, mule-studio

I have a requirement like transferring a file from a inbound directory to a outbound directory using file connector in Mule. While transferring the file it is processed in a working directory configured in the input file connector.
Now, my requirement is , if I place an old file in the file input directory, the  file in the working directory should have the current time stamp on the system date modified.
It is something similar like "**Touch**" command used in Unix to set the system modified date.

Please not I don't want to use any Groovy Script method or any other hack method that can affect the performance in order to achieve this.
Following is my Mule mflow:-

```
<file:connector name="File"     autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" outputAppend="true"/>
<file:connector name="File1" autoDelete="false" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<flow name="FileReadandDeleteFlow1" doc:name="FileReadandDeleteFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint   responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="File" moveToDirectory="E:\backup\test_workingDir"  path="E:\backup\test" moveToPattern="processingFile.xml">
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="E:\backup\test_out" outputPattern="Finaloutput.txt" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File1" doc:name="File"/>
```

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `#[function:dateStamp]` or `#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]` to achieve this as described in this [link](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/File+Transport+Reference#FileTransportReference-Usage)

An example would be :

`<file:outbound-endpoint path="E:\backup\test_out" outputPattern="Finaloutput_[function:dateStamp].txt" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File1" doc:name="File"/>`

**EDIT:**

To always show the current timestamp to your files in working firectory, you can create another flow which reads files from working directory at a specific interval, and just copy them to same directory using `file:outbound-endpoint`

Comment: Thanks for your comment .. But I am not trying to change the file name  to current time stamp... I am trying to set the system modified date on the file to current time stamp... for example :- If I place an old file that I have created 5 months ago to the inbound folder I will get a file in my working directory ...  This file in the working directory will have system timestamp that shows modified date 5 month old...  This system timestamp can be seen by setting details option in view menu of Windows ... I want to modify this system timestamp using Mule

Comment: Question is not clear.. Do you want an updated stamp without processing the file or the file will be processed?

Comment: I want the system should show Date Modified as the current date time for the file in working Directory. For Example if I place a file that I have created 3 month before in the inbound folder, the mule file connector will process it and place the file in working directory. Now the file in the working directory, The system will show Date modified as old date ( 3 month old) .. Now I need the system to show Date modified as current time stamp for this file in the working directory ...  Hope I am clear now .. I want to set the system date modified for the file in working dir

Comment: Do you mean you always want to show the current time stamp to files in working directory?

Comment: yes.. but not in file name ... I want current time stamp for the file in system modified date ....      That is, when ever the file comes to the working directory, the windows system time stamp must show the date modified as current datetime

Comment: did you see my updated answer... it does exactly what you expect. Update timestamp in file system without changing filename.

Answer (score 1):

we have mel using this we cal achieve current date and time

```
[server.dateTime.format("yyyyMMddhhmmss")].txt
```

The format u like we can set in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<file:outbound-endpoint path="YOUR_PATH" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:yyyyMMdd-HHmmssSSSSSS]
_#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Backup In Mule"/>
```